# Running multiple jobs in make cause server to crash?

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, makefile, gnu-make

Could running multiple jobs in make cause server to crash?

For example:

`make -j 20 all`

If the server handling this request is already under heavy use, and say, has only 20 processors, would the server crash? Or would the make jobs simply be denied?

Edit: 
The reason for the question: A co-worker of mine said the other day that my using multiple jobs was causing the server to crash. My guess was that the server would give a "Virtual Memory Exhausted" statement or simply deny the jobs before it crashed.

Comment: Neither? "Threads" (e.g. one "job") are a programming idea, and doesn't match one to one with the architecture. I allow all these threads to run programatically at once.  However, the jobs are processed in the cores. This means that you can have up to n instructions running at the same time. If you have n+m threads, they compete for resources, but the don't crash, they are queued by the scheduler. You CAN crash your computer with too many jobs (say from too much ram required), but only large projects with many dependencies will have that many jobs that can run at once.

Comment: `make -j all` (i.e., no job limit at all) however, can be expected to give your server a big headache. Disk thrashing, memory exhaustion, process slot exhaustion... all kinds of crimes-against-hardware. It may take you some time to re-gain control, but no, it shouldn't crash. Why the question?

Answer (score 0):

> would the server crash?

No, it shouldn't crash, unless you encountered a bug in your or somebody's program. It should continue to work (although slower because of heavy load).

> Or would the make jobs simply be denied?

No, linux is not designed to prevent process creation. Of course, it has a limit how many processes can run in parallel (other OSs as well), since computers do not have unlimited resources.